# Worpdress default forget password is not changing password in database .

Tags: php, wordpress, forgot-password

I am using wordpress 4.7.3 .Just used the wordpress default forget password link. After hitting the password reset link (which i got through email), i changed the password (new). It doens't effect the password inside the database.

Now when i changed that users password from the wordpress admin, it works fine. Here is the link i get for new password:

> http://my_site.com/wp-login.php?action=rp

But i dont know why its not affecting the database. Someone else faced this isse?